# Moving pdf files to a specific directory

Tags: file, file-transfer

I am using ubuntu.  I have about 500 directories in the current working directory.  I want to transfer any pdf files that exist in these directories to a specific location.  What can I do?

Have been copying from the Caja but this is very time consuming.

I have been using `rsync` to transfer whole directory trees.

Comment: Could you define "transfer" more precisely?  Are they being uploaded via some proprietary protocol or something more standard

Comment: No proprietary protocol.  Just a tree directory structure with different types of files.

Comment: What code have you tried?  Am asking because this site is mostly about code related issues, the Unix stackexchange site would probably be better for a bash oneliner for moving lots of files around